# Flawed Hamming distance heuristic for 8-puzzle (A* search)

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

An inadmissible heuristic can cause A* to fail to find the optimal path to a goal. For example, suppose the search tree has only two branches:

```
A -1-> B -1-> C
A -3-> D
```

That is, the step from A to B costs 1, the step from B to C costs 1, and the step from A to D costs 3. A is the root and C and D are both goals.

If an inadmissible heuristic gives an estimate of 3 for B, A* search will expand D before C, thus finding a path to a goal that is not the least expensive (3 rather than 2).

Now, consider the 8-puzzle. Suppose we implement a flawed Hamming distance heuristic where we count the blank as a tile. This is clearly inadmissible because it gives an estimate of 2 for a state 1 move from the goal.

My question: is there a (hopefully small) example where this causes A* to fail to find the goal closest to the root (or at least expand more nodes than necessary)?

Comment: when you say "fail to find the goal closest to the root", what do you mean? A* finishes when it finds a path from the source to ANY goal node.

Comment: I mean that if there is, say, one goal node 5 steps from the root and another 7 steps away, it finds the one 7 steps away. It finds a goal, but not the one closest to the root.

Comment: This is clearly a homework problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: It's the other way around, BlueRaja: I'm the instructor, and I'm trying to find a way to explain to the students why this heuristic (which many of them turned in) doesn't work. I've shown an example for why an admissible heuristic doesn't work in general, but I'd like to have one that works specifically for the 8-puzzle.